# How to get the sum of the array of specific value

Tags: php

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [gender] => F
            [thisweektotal] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [gender] => M
            [thisweektotal] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [gender] => Adult
            [thisweektotal] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [gender] => Young Adult
            [thisweektotal] => 4
        )

)
```

I want the sum of thisweektotal of the gender M and F only that is 5
I have tried the below code but i am not getting sum of all the gender F and I want only the sum of the genders M and F

```
foreach($analytics_data['this_week'] as $value) 
  {

    if($value['gender']=='M' || $value['gender']=='F')
    {
      $total_this_week_arr = array_column($value['thisweektotal'], 'thisweektotal');
      $this_week_total = array_sum($total_this_week_arr);

    }

  }
 echo "this_week_total=".$this_week_total;
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please, if an answer below has helped you, please mark it as the "accepted answer" to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution [using array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) with the third paramter which works because you don't have conflicting values in the "gender" key transforming the array to a much simplier structure for summing.

```
$gender = array_column( $array, 'thisweektotal', 'gender' );
$total = $gender['M'] + $gender['F'];
```

If there is a chance of a missing key we can try using [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) as a sort of a "*whitelist filter*" to your array...

```
$gender = array_column( $array, 'thisweektotal', 'gender' );
$filtered = array_intersect_key( $gender, array_flip( array( 'M', 'F' ) ) );
$total = array_sum( $filtered );
```

Comment: i like this approach, its small and clean. but do you know for sure gender is unique? - if the answer is yes, this is the best solution for it.

Comment: You're correct, if there's duplicate rows that share the same gender value this will fail. I just wanted to add a solution that wasn't reliant on obvious iteration :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looping, you dont need the `array_column` and `array_sum`. You can just:

```
$this_week_total = 0;

foreach($analytics_data['this_week'] as $value)  {
    if( $value['gender'] == 'M' || $value['gender'] == 'F' )
    {
      $total_this_week_arr = $value['thisweektotal'];
      $this_week_total += $total_this_week_arr ;
    }
}

echo "this_week_total = " .$this_week_total;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through the array just you need a variable which holds the sum value

```
$sum = 0;//Your variable which stores the value of sum

foreach($analytics_data['this_week'] as $k=>$arr){
    if($arr['gender']=='F' || $arr['gender']=='M')
    $sum+=$arr['thisweektotal']; //Adding sum to $sum
}

echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$aInput = [
    [
        "gender" => "F",
        "thisweektotal" => 3,
    ], [
        "gender" => "M",
        "thisweektotal" => 2,
    ], [
        "gender" => "Adult",
        "thisweektotal" => 1,
    ], [
        "gender" => "Young Adult",
        "thisweektotal" => 4,
    ]
];

$iSum = array_reduce($aInput, function($sum, $el) {
    if (in_array($el['gender'], ['F', 'M'])) {
        $sum += $el['thisweektotal'];
    }
    return $sum;
});

var_dump($iSum);
```